# Mysql query date between dates

Tags: mysql

I want to select the records that have a specific in between date, let me explain this in an example:
I have this table:

```
contracts
id | date_start | date_finish
1  | 2011-01-01 | 2011-01-15
2  | 2012-02-15 | 2012-03-15
3  | 2012-02-16 | 2012-02-25
```

I want to show the contracts that were open in this date '2012-02-17', if I do this query it would output contracts 2 and 3, if I searched this date '2012-03-14' it would output contract 2...how can I make this query?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE your_date BETWEEN date_start AND date_finish
```

However, I think *"if I searched this date '2012-03-14' it would output contract 3.."* should ouptut contract 2, since 2012-03-14 is between 2012-02-15 and 2012-03-15.

Comment: I didn't know that I could use between like that...THANKS!!